# Custom Random Number Generator

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get an extremely fast, but reliable (Same input = same output, so I can't use time) pseudo-random number generator? I want the end result to be something like `float NumGen( int x, int y, int seed );` so that it creates a random number between 0 and 1 based on those three values. I found several random number generators, but I can't get them to work, and the random number generator that comes with Unity is far to slow to use. I have to make about 9 calls to the generator per 1 meter of terrain, so I don't really care if it's not perfectly statistically random, just that it works really quickly. Does anyone know of an algorithm that fits my needs? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. A linear congruence generator is two lines of code.

Comment: I would look into `System.Random` generation. It does use time but if you swap that time for your seed, or even combine the two, you get what I think you describe here.

Comment: @EricLippert I can't find a away to implement a linear congruence generator to take 3 inputs and still work 0f-1f.

Comment: @WoutervanderHouven That's what I was using, but I'm calling the function hundreds of times per second so the complex algorithm they use is very resource demanding

Comment: @NicholasPipitone: Why would you want it to take three inputs? I am confused as to what you're actually asking here.  You want to associate a triple of integers with a pseudo-random double? Are the integers that are the coordinates some well-specified range, like they go from zero to 100 or something?

Comment: @EricLippert They are coordinates to a plane I'm using to generate Perlin Noise, but it has to be infinite so I need the coordinates so that if I generate some noise over here, I can predict the noise of the nearby terrain and smooth it out before that terrain is even loaded.

Comment: Got it. So just generating a big sequence of 10000 random numbers isn't going to do the trick.  An additional complication is that you're going to be generating numbers for, say, (100, 200) and then (100, 201) and (99, 200) and so on; the coordinates are not adding any entropy.  I don't know offhand of an algorithm that does what you want but I'll give it some thought.

Comment: The .NET Random class is fairly simple (Knuth's subtractive algo)...  A linear congruence generator might seem simpler in terms of understanding and implementation; but, I don't think it would be noticeable quicker than `System.Random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you had to create a *Random* instance on every call to *NumGen*. To get the function to return the same number for the same parameters you could use a hash function.

I tested a few things, and this code was about 3 times faster than recreating intances of *Random*.

```
//System.Security.Cryptography
static MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
static byte[] outbuf;
static byte[] inbuf = new byte[12];
static float floatHash(uint x, uint y, uint z) {
    inbuf[0]= (byte)(x >> 24);
    inbuf[1]=(byte)(x >> 16);
    inbuf[2]=(byte)(x >> 8);
    inbuf[3]=(byte)(x);
    inbuf[4]=(byte)(y >> 24);
    inbuf[5]=(byte)(y >> 16);
    inbuf[6]=(byte)(y >> 8);
    inbuf[7]=(byte)(y);
    inbuf[8]=(byte)(z >> 24);
    inbuf[9]=(byte)(z >> 16);
    inbuf[10]=(byte)(z >> 8);
    inbuf[11]=(byte)(z);
    outbuf = hasher.ComputeHash(inbuf);
    return ((float)BitConverter.ToUInt64(outbuf, 0))/ulong.MaxValue;
}
```

Another method using some RSA methods is about 5 times faster than *new System.Random(seed)*:

```
static uint prime = 4294967291;
static uint ord = 4294967290;
static uint generator = 4294967279;
static uint sy;
static uint xs;
static uint xy;
static float getFloat(uint x, uint y, uint seed) {
    //will return values 1=> x >0; replace 'ord' with 'prime' to get 1> x >0
    //one call to modPow would be enough if all data fits into an ulong
    sy = modPow(generator, (((ulong)seed) << 32) + (ulong)y, prime);
    xs = modPow(generator, (((ulong)x) << 32) + (ulong)seed, prime);
    xy = modPow(generator, (((ulong)sy) << 32) + (ulong)xy, prime);
    return ((float)xy) / ord;
}
static ulong b;
static ulong ret;
static uint modPow(uint bb, ulong e, uint m) {
    b = bb;
    ret = 1;
    while (e > 0) {
        if (e % 2 == 1) {
            ret = (ret * b) % m;
        }
        e = e >> 1;
        b = (b * b) % m;
    }
    return (uint)ret;
}
```

I ran a test to generate 100000 floats. I used the index as seed for System.Random and as x parameter of floatHash (y and z were 0).

> System.Random: Min: 2.921559E-06 Max: 0.9999979 Repetitions: 0
>
> floatHash MD5: Min: 7.011156E-06 Max: 0.9999931 Repetitions: 210 (values were returned twice)
>
> getFloat RSA: Min: 1.547858E-06 Max: 0.9999989 Repetitions: 190

Comment: Are you sure the output is RANDOM? All i can see is that you are hashing a byte array and dividing the result by ulong.maxvalue? How is that supposed to be random?

Comment: It's not perfectly random. I edited a test report into the answer.

Comment: This appears to be perfect, but I'm having trouble using it. I'm using Unity and for some reason is crashes every time I try to run it. I don't think it likes uint's because I tried dealing with them earlier and it took an extremely long time. Is there a way to convert it to solely int's because I'm not sure how the code works and the bit-wise operators appear to be dependent on the bit length.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone I edited the code. Now are all integers unsigned. There was an integer overflow caused by the conversion of negative integers to ulong.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are underestimating the `System.Random` class.  It is quite speedy.  I believe your slow down is related to creating a new instance of the `Random` class on each call to your `NumGen` method.

In my quick test I was able to generate 100,000 random numbers using `System.Random` in about 1 millisecond.

To avoid the slow down consider seed points in your 2D plane.  Disperse the seed points so that they cover a distance no greater than 100,000 meters.  Then associate (or calculate) the nearest seed point for each meter, and use that point as your seed to `System.Random`.

Yes, you will be generating a ton of random numbers you will never use, but they are virtually free.

Pseudo-code:

```
double NumGen(x, y, distance, seed) {
  Random random = new Random(seed);
  double result = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<distance; i++) {
    result = random.NextDouble();
  }
}
```

You could modify this simple outline to return a sequence of random numbers (possibly representing a grid), and couple that with a caching mechanism.  That would let you conserve memory and improve (lessen) CPU consumption.

Comment: Indeed if you have only one instance (or a few instances) of the Random class, the performance will be great, obviously depends on the variables you use for measuring.